# bundler version claims to exist, but does not

Tags: bundler

How can this be explained and remedied?

```
-bash> gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (default: 2.2.21)

-bash> bundler --version
Bundler version 2.1.4

-bash> gem uninstall bundler:2.1.4
Gem 'bundler' is not installed

-bash> gem environment | grep INSTALL
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.7.0

-bash> find /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/ -name "bundler*"                   
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//bin/bundler                                    
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/2.7.0/exe/bundler                     
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb                      
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler                         
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-2.2.21.gemspec
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler              
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/cache/bundler-2.2.21.gem   
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/doc/bundler-2.2.21         
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/doc/bundler-2.2.27         
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.8.1/lib/bootsnap/bundler.rb
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21        
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.21/exe/bundler
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rubocop-1.13.0/lib/rubocop/cop/bundler
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.4/lib/bootsnap/bundler.rb
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rubocop-1.21.0/lib/rubocop/cop/bundler
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/simplecov-0.17.1/lib/simplecov/profiles/bundler_filter.rb
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bundler                    
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/LockfileParser/bundler_version-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/bundler_major_version-c.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/Standalone/bundler_path-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/Plugin/API/Source/bundler_plugin_api_source%3f-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/Fetcher/bundler_cert_store-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/CLI/Gem/bundler_dependency_version-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Bundler/SharedHelpers/bundler_ruby_lib-i.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Gem/BundlerVersionFinder/bundler_version_with_reason-c.ri
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//share/ri/2.7.0/system/Gem/BundlerVersionFinder/bundler_version-c.ri
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain it, but the remedy is:

1. Remove `bundler-2.2.21.gemspec` from the folder that renders it `default`:
2. Reinstall the desired version.

---

Uninstalling `bundler` will not work:

```
-bash> gem uninstall bundler
Gem bundler-2.2.21 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem
```

Note the following line in the output of the `find` command above:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-2.2.21.gemspec
```

Remove it in order to remove the "default" status of this gem:

```
rm /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4//lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/specifications/default/bundler-2.2.21.gemspec
```

Uninstalling is now impossible...

```
-bash> gem uninstall bundler
Gem 'bundler' is not installed
```

Indeed...

```
-bash> bundler --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
        1: from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.4/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.1.4) required by your /Users/me/Projects/kinside/kinside/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.1.4`
```

So install the desired version:

```
-bash> gem install bundler:2.2.21
Successfully installed bundler-2.2.21
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.2.21
Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.2.21
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Check:

```
-bash> bundler --version
Bundler version 2.2.21

-bash> gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.2.21)
```